# Back button handling in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I've got several ASP.NET webforms in a "wizard-like" workflow:

form A  is submitted, redirect to form B. Form B is submitted, redirect to Form C. Form C is submitted, redirect to Success.Aspx which tells the user the submission has succeeded and database has been updated.

At that point, the user should not be able to return to Form C and resubmit.  However, if the user, on Success.aspx, clicks the browser's back button, no server-side event seems to fire on Form C. Page_Load does not fire again. Can Form C know that it is being revisited, and if so, how?

Or if Form C has know way of knowing that it is being revisited, is there some setting that can set in the server-side Submit-handler on Form C that would cause the page to expire and redirect user to Form A?

P.S. I've tried setting cache expiration in the Page_Load of my Form C but it did not cause the Page_Load to refire when revisiting the page using the Back button:

```
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
            Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
            Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
```

P.P.S. But this (from the link in the comment by @gh9) has the desired effect:

```
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("no-cache");
        Response.Expires = 0;
```

Comment: http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/resolving-browser-back-button-with-caching-pages/

a Quick google on 'respond to back button asp.net' brought up a ton of answers

Comment: The reason why nothing is fired is the page is loaded from browser cache. No new request is made. Also is there a reason for all the redirects? You could handle all this on the one aspx page with `asp:Panels` that you show/hide as required?

Comment: @gh9: Those Google answers don't have upvotes to tell me that their approach is best practice. That's why we come here to SO, isn't it?

Comment: @Jon P:  I've tried setting cache expiration in code-behind for my Form C, and it had no effect.

Comment: @Tim Well, if you read [ask], you'll find that it tells you to Search, then research, before asking a question on Stack Overflow, so, no, that's not what SO is for.

Comment: We'll have to disagree, @Mike McCaughan. SO is not just for getting answers, but for getting answers which other members corroborate by upvoting. I had searched, but the answers I had found (see my first attempt to set the cache) were not working.  So that if someone were to make gh9's comment an answer, and it got upvoted, someone down the road would see that it was the preferred method. There are many questions on SO which have huge numbers of upvotes, and many answers as well.  You can feel confident that such an answer is a good one. The upvotes help to distinguish signal from noise.

Answer (score 1):

I found this which might help you:

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/11/disable-browser-back-button.html

Author: Suresh Dasari

> In the header of the page, place this JavaScript that should work in all browsers to prevent the user from reaching pages using the back button.
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
> function DisableBackButton() {
> window.history.forward()
> }
> DisableBackButton();
> window.onload = DisableBackButton;
> window.onpageshow = function(evt) { if (evt.persisted) DisableBackButton() }
> window.onunload = function() { void (0) }
> </script>
> ```

The JavaScript will cause the browser to go forward as though the user hit the forward button in the browser.

> You can also change the caching of the page so that it will display as expired if the user tries to go back to it.
>
> Add the following to the top of the file:
>
> ```
> using System.Web;
> ```
>
> In Page_Init or Page_Load event method do the following:
>
> ```
> Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
> Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
> Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
> ```

From experience, I can tell you the Javascript portion is a good fix to stop users from using the backbutton.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. ;)

Comment: I've read that disabling the back button is bad practice, and I'd rather try to find a solution that causes my Page_Load event to (re)fire in code-behind.